# flutter SelectableLinkify - links not working

Tags: flutter

I'm using the flutter_linkify package, running on iOS.

I've got it working fine using the Linkify widget.

BUT when I use SelectableLinkify: links still show using the link style (blue underline) BUT links no longer load when clicked.

Any ideas on what might be wrong / how to debug?

Thank you!

code to replicate:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:flutter_linkify/flutter_linkify.dart';

class TestingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestingScreenState createState() => _TestingScreenState();
}

class _TestingScreenState extends State<TestingScreen> {
  _launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SelectableLinkify(
            onOpen: (link) {
              _launchURL(link.url);
            },
            text:
            'I have an awesome website https://google.com',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter Doctor output (note I'm not using VS Code so shouldn't impact this project!)

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-AU)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[!] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```